# IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information

Tags: php, paypal

I referred all the previous stackoverflow answers regarding this. but I am not clear what to do with my case.

```
IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information.
```

This is the error I am getting when sending ipn message using ipn simulator..

I am using the script from

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

I am just checking this with sandbox account

and I am not using https site. I am using only http.

even I tried

```
             CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
```

cacert.pem contains https://www.symantec.com/content/dam/symantec/docs/other-resources/verisign-class-3-public-primary-certification-authority-g5-en.pem

even I changed the    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false but didn't work

I don't know what to do please help

update: I removed everything in the listener page and put just file_put_contents("ipntest.txt", var_export($_POST, true)); still the same error and ipntest.txt file is alse not created
Thanks,

Comment: Do u want to Send IPN or do u want to Retrieve IPN ?

Comment: check cacert is valid or not

Comment: @KikiTheOne both I am testing it in my development server. I am sending ipn using ipn simulator from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ And I want process in my development server which is just http

Comment: for retrieving check the answer below. i deleted it cause i had 1 querstion before :D it is simple $_POST what PayPal sends u.

Answer (score 6):

As of now (March 2017) IPN Simulator doesn't seem to work at all. Use Sandbox accounts to initiate normal payment cycle; it does work.

Comment: Ugh that explains a lot!

Comment: I am not sure.
I have got the Sandbox payment workingon March 5, 2017 but since March 10, 2017 it does not work anymore.
Trying IPN I am getting this error.

Comment: Was debugging my listener yesterday - Sandbox worked for me, although sometimes it takes hours or even days for it to send confirmations. (sometimes re-sending them manually helps).

Simulator, nope, it doesn't even connect to the listener.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Sandbox is upgraded and only accept SSL connection with TLSv1.2 (TLS 1.1 and lower versions of SSL are not accepted). You would need to ensure your apacha / OpenSSL supports tlsv1.2, pls run the command on your terminal and verify:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443
```

Typically upgrading your OpenSSL to 1.0.1 or higher would work.

Comment: I run the code it shows at the last line Verify return code: 0 (ok). should my site to be upgraded with https. can't I use curl to do this?

Comment: I've got this same error, the confusing thing is that the server is already hosting two other sites which are working with PayPal fine, the command-line check comes back "Verify return code: 0 (ok)", and states it's using TLS 1.2.

Answer (score -1):

U Should Use te PayPal IPN Simulator.
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/

The PayPal IPN is nothing u have to CURL.

PayPal sends a Basic $_POST to the defined Address. so u just have to use `$_POST['payment_type']`

Sometimes u Need to `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');` .

In My Case the $_POST from a Test Looks like this.

```
$._POST:{payment_type=instant&payment_date=Mon+May+30+2016+08%3A47%3A06+GMT+0200+%28Mitteleurop%E4ische+Sommerzeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=Scriptkiddie&last_name=StackOverflow&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=AK-1234&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=136666829&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AnKUojs05l5xK--wKubHCkCuzwmCAxnK4WCLxW3c2aUgJNx4ufcY8RSh}
```